# Ubuntu One post-installation bug

Tags: discussion

I'd posted a question regarding this error message that i get after installing Ubuntu One. the question was closed and it was suggested that i file a bug report. I checked online and someone has already posted this bug on Launchpad's site. So, what's my next option? And is there anyway i can help in resolving bugs?
The error that i received was -

> CredentialsError
>
> DBusException(dbus.string(u'Process /usr/lib/ubuntu-sso-client/ubuntu-sso-login exited with status 1'),)

Ideas, folks?

Comment: I think we can migrate this to main and rephrase it as a "How to use Launchpad?" Q. Long story short: If the bug is already filed, there's a number of ways to follow, extend, support and otherwise handle Launchpad bugs. You will, however, have to wait for either a workaround or a bug fix for your problem to be solved.

Comment: This should be closed, BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These have already been answered on the main site. You can find your answer regarding this on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20119/how-do-i-subscribe-to-a-bug) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5347/how-can-i-get-bug-reporting-help?rq=1). They describe how you can follow a bug and how you can help resolve bugs.